# Recibiendo resultados inesperados e incorrectos SPRINGBOOT HIBERNATE

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, jpa

(esta pregunta tiene una version en ingles: [Pregunta Stackoverflow ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345868/reciving-more-data-than-expected))

Hola,
Estoy creando una API-REST con springboot y hibernate.
En uno de los controladores, estoy retornando una entidad, el caso es que cuando lo hago de esta forma:

```
 Empresa company= empresaManager.findById(2L);
 return company;
```

Devuelve exactamente lo que esperaba (el objeto empresa con su listado de estudiantes, los cuales solo son 2 vinculados en la BBDD ).

Pero en cambio, si no uso un numero, si lo que hago es coger el estudiante y despues retornar la empresa que el esta vinculado, me devuelve la empresa con 12 alumnos vinculados (6 veces repetido cada uno)

```
String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
token = token.replace("Bearer ", "");
Usuario usuario = tokenManager.getUsuarioFromToken(token);
Long id = usuario.getEmpresa().getIdempresa();
Empresa empresaOriginal = empresaManager.findById(id);
return empresaOriginal;
```

Alguna posibilidad de que sepais como solucionarlo ?
La entidad empresa que se deberia retornar es así:

[image]

Y asi es como la estoy recibiendo:

[image]

### Entidades y getByID

User entity :

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "usuario")
  public class Usuario {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "idusuario")
  private Long idusuario;

  @Column(name = "nombre", length = 30, nullable = false)
  private String nombre;

  @Column(name = "email", length = 80, nullable = false)
  private String email;

  @JsonIgnore
  @Column(name = "contraseña", length = 300, nullable = false)
  private String contraseña;

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "empresa_idempresa"), name = "empresa_idempresa")
  private Empresa empresa;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Fichaje> fichajes;

  public Usuario() {
  }


  public Empresa getEmpresa() {
    return empresa;
  }


  public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
    this.empresa = empresa;
  }
}
```

Company entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empresa")
public class Empresa {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "idempresa")
  private Long idempresa;

  @Column(name = "nombre", length = 100, nullable = false)
  private String nombre;

  @Column(name = "contacto", length = 300, nullable = false)
  private String contacto;

  @Column(name = "fecha_inicio_practicas", columnDefinition = "DATE")
  private LocalDate inicioPracticas;

  @Column(name = "direccion", length = 100)
  private String direccion;

  @Column(name = "foto_empresa")
  private String fotoEmpresa;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<EmpresaTieneDia> empresaTieneDias;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Usuario> estudiantes;

  public Empresa() {
  }


  public Long getIdempresa() {
    return idempresa;
  }

  public void setIdempresa(Long idempresa) {
    this.idempresa = idempresa;
  }


  public List<Usuario> getEstudiantes() {
    return estudiantes;
  }

  public void setEstudiantes(List<Usuario> estudiantes) {
    this.estudiantes = estudiantes;
  }
}
```

Así es como hago el findById: 
(Service or Manager)

```
public Empresa findById(Long id) {
    return this.empresaRepository.findByIdempresa(id);
}
```

(Repository or DAO)

```
public interface EmpresaRepository extends CrudRepository<Empresa, Long> {
    Empresa findByIdempresa(Long id);
}
```

Comment: Me parece que el problema está aquí: `List<Usuario> estudiantes`. Prueba cambiando la lista por un `Set`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta reemplazar este fragmento:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "empresa", orphanRemoval = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, 
  cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<Usuario> estudiantes;
```

Si no funciona tal vez deberías considerar crear dos métodos para obtener uno para los datos de la empresa y otro para la lista de estudiantes.
Investiga y considera usar Set para las listas de todas la entidades y FetchType.LAZY en vez de FetchType.EAGER.

También considera en no exponer las entidades como servicio web. Es mejor usar una clase que represente lo que realmente necesites exponer, por que si expones toda la entidad estarías mostrando mas datos de los que realmente necesitas.

Crea capas "repository", "service" y "controller". Es es recomendable que desarrolles de manera desacoplada.

Si no logras resolverlo escríbeme estoy seguro que puedo ayudarte.
Hay varios temas relacionados del porque piensas que falla el Hibernate. Temas como Session , JPA, la conversion de la entidad a JSON, etc.

Comment: Si, se ha solucionado el error a la hora de usar un Set para la lista de estudiantes. Muchas gracias !!  Me podias explicar el por que ocurre esto si es un List en vez de un Set.  Por cierto, tengo todo estructurado por capas y utilizo las entidades directamente con el Json ignore para lo que no quiero mostrar.

Comment: Bueno aquí hay una explicación detalla y rápida de List y Set en Java. http://net-informations.com/java/cjava/list.htm

Básicamente Set no admite duplicados.